# Working HTTPS Server in Haskell

Tags: windows, haskell, yesod

I'm trying to make simple https server in haskell, and possibly due to my ignorance, it was feeled hard to me.

The following is *compilable* code snippet that I reached. (and maybe not working)

```
import Application () -- for YesodDispatch instance
import Foundation
import Yesod.Core

import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.Wai.Handler.WarpTLS

main :: IO ()
main = do
  app <- toWaiApp App
  runTLS tSet defaultSettings app

tSet = tlsSettings "server.crt" "server.pem"
```

It's just part of Main.hs of `stack new proj yesod-minimal` project, with warp-tls dependencies.

But builded excutable had some problems,

- Not accissible by web browser due to TLS error.
- CPU usage go high (like infinite loop) on some request.

I wonder where or what is I went wrong. Followings are questions.

1. how can I deal with TLS error. The following is curl error log.

```
cmd>curl https://localhost:3000 --insecure -v
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:3000/
*   Trying ::1...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:04091077:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:wrong signature length
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
curl: (35) error:04091077:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:wrong signature length
```

executable log

```
24/Oct/2015:15:50:15 +0900 [Info#yesod-core] Application launched @(yesod_2EJXksqBDOz5UARIVdQquS:Yesod.Core.Dispatch .\Yesod\Core\Dispatch.hs:157:11)
.exe: HandshakeFailed (Error_Misc "user error (unexpected type received. expecting handshake and got: Alert [(AlertLevel_Fatal,DecryptError)])")
.exe: HandshakeFailed (Error_Protocol ("fallback is not allowed",True,InappropriateFallback))
.exe: HandshakeFailed (Error_Misc "user error (unexpected type received. expecting handshake and got: Alert [(AlertLevel_Fatal,DecryptError)])")
.exe: HandshakeFailed (Error_Protocol ("fallback is not allowed",True,InappropriateFallback))
```

2. How treat CPU high phenomenon from unknown reason. [cpu usage images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BWVP.png)
   I don't know what debug info would be helpful in this case.
3. Current GHC 7.10.2 can fire compile time error due to windows' command line length limitation, and I was suffered from that. I tried setting STACK_ROOT and shorting project path, but yesod-simple template project can't be built.
   There's another workthrough or hack that I can try? I even tried manually building ghc 7.11 in git repo, but it seems stack don't support use of newer GHC.
4. A little off from subject, `toWaiApp` function in above code, I believed the function's existence, but it was hard to find function's name. It came out that yesod maintains stackage documentation rather than hackage's. Is there any convenient method like python module docs?
5. Shouldn't I have selected haskell? It's far from something performance critical, but is there something critical like flaw of Haskell's TLS implementation or lack of build tool's support for windows?